# How do I access my swift classes from my UI tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I have a UI test like so :

```
    func testHome(){
         if(isRedOrange.clear()){
                //code
            }
    }
```

How would I access my isRedOrange.clear function from my isRedOrange.swift file from my UI tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754696/uitest-color-of-a-label-not-ui-label

Answer (score 25):

UI Tests are black boxed, so **you cant have access to your code**.

You can use `@testable import` in **Unit Tests**, so full access will be provided.
When you're running UITests this is not working, because during a UITest your test class cannot access your app's code.

From Apple's Docs:

> UI testing differs from unit testing in fundamental ways. Unit testing
>   enables you to work within your app's scope and allows you to exercise
>   functions and methods with full access to your app's variables and
>   state. UI testing exercises your app's UI in the same way that users
>   do without access to your app's internal methods, functions, and
>   variables. This enables your tests to see the app the same way a user
>   does, exposing UI problems that users encounter.

You must achieve everything using `.tap()`'s on elements. `.accessibilityIdentifier` will help you to get the right element

Comment: It really surprises me that one can't define the data or flow of the app from the test suite. What Apple seem to be pushing people towards is what I think of as integration testing, whereas I want to write atomic tests which will test parts of the app's UI based on a supplied view model, and I don't want to have to re-write my queries if I happen to change the app flow.

Answer (score 9):

Goto projects settings -> Select uitests target -> build phases tab -> add your swift file to compile sources

Comment: That worked for.  Just wanted to use some existing model structs to pass some test data in.

Comment: I was wondering if this really works. As I understood Ui Tests and the app are like 2 different applications running side by side. So will adding a file to a second app will remove the syntax errors? yea... but will have any impact on the main app ?

won't this just execute code @ the "ui project" rather than having any affect in the app we are testing?

Comment: @JoãoSerra that's correct. The UI tests and the app are compiled separately, so the tests cannot, for instance, directly call a function within the app. You can, however, make source code available to both the app and the tests (as this answer explains). Then the tests and the app can share algorithms and data structures. They still run separately though.

Comment: Another way is to open the specific files to use with the test target, go to the File Inspector (right panel of Xcode) and under Target Membership tick the test target

Comment: @Dan If I do that I get build errors "Undefined symbol: ...".

Answer (score 3):

You need to import your main module (project) into tests:

- Ensure you've set `ENABLE_TESTABILITY` in `Build Settings` of the main project target to true.

[image: enable_testability]

- To import it into tests, call `@testable import MAIN_TARGET_NAME` in your UITests file.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but where should `@testable import MAIN_TARGET_NAME` be located at? below import UIKit? Also, upon doing that my class is not showing

Comment: im using swift .

Comment: it says `No such module 'InternetAvailabilty.swift'`

Comment: The same way as you import the module `UIKit` using `import UIKit`, you will use `@testable import YOUR_APP` to import your main target. Also, if you just have a global function `func clear()`, you just call it with `clear()`, you never call the filename in Swift

Comment: what is you target's name? not the Swift file, but the target in Xcode?

Comment: its called hd-team

Comment: I edited my answer with some pictures to make it more clear

Comment: This works for **Unit** Tests, but _not_ for **UI** Tests.

Answer (score -2):

The question makes no sense. You don’t access *any* of your app’s code in a UI test. If you want to access your code, write a unit test.

Comment: In my case, I needed to mock `NSOpenPanel` to provide a consistent output in UI tests, so I defined a protocol and extended `NSOpenPanel` to adopt it. I also defined a mock class in my UI Test target that also adopts the protocol. The protocol definition needs to be available to both the app and the UI tests. I just moved the protocol to its own source file and set its "Target Membership" to both app and UI tests.

Comment: Wait, I realized can't inject my mock class from the UI test target anyway... I have to somehow determine whether I am being UI-tested from the app itself (and use either `NSOpenPanel` or mock its behavior and returned URL). The app code really is inaccessible from the UI Test target. Makes perfect sense though, since UI tests are based on macOS's accessibility features...