# How to check background color of the XCUIElement in UI test cases??

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ui-testing, xcuitest

I am working on one issue where I need to change the Textfield's background color to the white color. I wanted to add the UI test case for it to check if background color of the `XCUIElement`(i.e Textfield) is white color or not. I searched for it but didn't not find any useful answer on it. I wanted to know if it is even possible check against background color in the UITest Cases.

I was going through Matt's answer, but didn't get clear idea.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754840/3278326

Thoughts?

Comment: no it's not possible, for the same reasons as explained by matt - the underlying label and its properties are not exposed in `XCUIElement`.

Comment: @Pranav Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: unit tests or snapshot tests

Comment: But unit test are meant for functional test, right?

Comment: If possible, Can you please provide example of snapshot test?

Comment: they are to test individual classes/modules. create a factory class or some setup function and test the color in that

Comment: look at PointFree snapshot testing - that's the best at the moment.

Comment: You can check an average color with https://github.com/devexperts/suitcase

Comment: Not sure why the question is closed. I have added enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like guys replied in comments, we can't do it by UI tests, but I think we still have 2 ways to achieve this:

1. [Snapshot Tests](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing):

   ```
    import SnapshotTesting
    ...
    func test_view_matchesSnapshot() {
        let view = makeYourView()
        assertSnapshot(matching: view, as: .wait(for: 1.5, on: .image))
    }
   ```
2. Unit Tests:

   ```
    func test_view_shouldHaveTextFieldWithExpectedBackgroundColor() throws {
        let view = makeYourView()

        let textFieldBackgroundColor = try XCTUnwrap(
            view.textField.backgroundColor, 
            "textField.backgroundColor is nil"
        )

        let expectedTextFieldBackgroundColor = UIColor.white

        XCTAssertEqual(
            textFieldBackgroundColor.toHexString(),
            expectedTextFieldBackgroundColor.toHexString(),
            "textField doesn't have expected backgroundColor"
        )
    }
   ```

*Utility hex getters to compare two UIColors can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151138/7203709)

**If your textField is private, then you can use
[this great solution](https://medium.com/@yuyaHorita/unit-test-of-private-iboutlet-in-uiviewcontroller-bdb6185809e0) and our unit test should look like this:

```
    func test_view_shouldHaveTextFieldWithExpectedBackgroundColor() throws {
        let view = makeYourView()

        let textField = try XCTUnwrap(
            YourViewMirror(reflecting: view).textField, 
            "Can't find textField property"
        )

        let textFieldBackgroundColor = try XCTUnwrap(
            textField.backgroundColor, 
            "textField.backgroundColor is nil"
        )

        let expectedTextFieldBackgroundColor = UIColor.white

        XCTAssertEqual(
            textFieldBackgroundColor.toHexString(),
            expectedTextFieldBackgroundColor.toHexString(),
            "textField doesn't have expected backgroundColor"
        )
    }
```

where

```
final class YourViewMirror: MirrorObject {
    init(reflecting yourView: YourView) {
        super.init(reflecting: yourView)
    }
    var textField: UITextField? {
        extract()
    }
}
```

and

```
class MirrorObject {
    let mirror: Mirror
    init(reflecting: Any) {
        self.mirror = Mirror(reflecting: reflecting)
    }

    func extract<T>(variableName: StaticString = #function) -> T? {
        return mirror.descendant("\(variableName)") as? T
    }
}
```